# update_one() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update'

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, mongodb

I literally tried everything under the sun, any suggestions how I can make it work? I have tried using ajax_data to get the right values updated but it didn't work. The purpose of this code is to be able to edit the values in a row and it would would submit the edits to the mongodb datab

```
    @portfolio_app.route('/editJob', methods=['POST'])
def editJob():
    try:

        ajax_data = request.get_json()
        print(request.get_json())

        db = connectToDB()

        collection_remote_jobs = db.remote_jobs
        print(collection_remote_jobs)

        collection_remote_jobs.update_one(
    {"$set":
        {"position": 'position',
        "company": "company",
        "description": "description"} 
    })

        return jsonify('Success it worked')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        return jsonify('Failed!')
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".table").off('click').on('click', '.edit', function(){
    var currentCell = $(this).parent().find(".cellvalue");
    var cellValue = currentCell.text();
    console.log(cellValue);
    currentCell.attr('contenteditable', 'true');
    alert("You can now start editing");
});

    $(".submitedit").click(function(){
        var position_data = $(this).parent().find(".gposition").text();
        var company_data = $(this).parent().find(".gcompany").text();
        var description_data = $(this).parent().find(".gdescription").text();
        console.log(position_data);
        console.log(company_data);
        console.log(description_data);
        var edit_job_data = {'position':position_data, 'company':company_data, 'description':description_data};
        var baseURL = window.location.origin; 
        var Post_URL = baseURL + '/editJob';
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: Post_URL,
            data: JSON.stringify(edit_job_data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg)   
                console.log('SUCCESS REACHED API!');
                alert('Job Info Has Been Delete!');
            }
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `update_one` query is missing the `filter` argument.

See the [docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one). You need to provide both a `filter` & a `update` dict. Right now you have only provided one, which `update_one` thinks is the `filter` - so it's complaining that the `update` part is missing.

You need to pass the filter as well:

```
collection_remote_jobs.update_one(
    { <some filter BSON that selects the document you want to update> },
    {"$set":
        {"position": 'position',
        "company": "company",
        "description": "description"} 
    }
)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be the filter be the same as  {"position": 'position',
        "company": "company",
        "description": "description"} ?

Comment: That depends on how your data is modeled, which document you need to update, and how you identify that document in the request. You are the best person to answer those questions.

Comment: but how do you update the database using the data I am pulling from my ajax call? Sorry I keep bothering you

Comment: You first need to decide which document you want to update. Does your database have only one document? Then you need the _id of that document. Then you can filter with `{_id: <the ID>}`